# Microsoft Azure Reports "Your app experienced failure(s) due to a transient storage access issue."

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure WebApp that continually reports "Your app experienced failure(s) due to a transient storage access issue."  The suggested solution is "Explore Local Cache feature for your web app." but my webapp exceeds the maximum storage (3GB) for this option.

The problem mostly occurs between midnight and 6am in the morning when the site is LEAST active, but there seems to be an increasing number of occurrences during the day.

What are the underlying causes of this problem? Is this something to do with my WebApp or is it the Azure Infrastructure. In either case, how do I determine the underlying issue(s) and resolve?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "Your app experienced failure(s) due to a transient storage access issue."

The Web Apps environment provides diagnostic functionality for logging information from both the web server and the web application. You could try to enable Logging and check the logs that generated within that period of time.

According to the error, it seems that a temporary issue causes app failure, and it suggests [enabling local cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache). You could follow the suggested solution and make sure if it helps resolve issue.

Besides, you could try to scale your web app (which would take additional charge) and check if it could mitigate the issue.

***Updates:***

As we know App Service offers a shared, persistent storage for the application. Maybe something wrong with the shared storage when the instances in farm access the storage, which may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: AS I said in my original post, I can't enable local cache as the app exceeds the maximum size of 3GB. 

Until I understand what is causing the issue I don't want to scale at additional cost.  The app runs well within limits on current scale.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the underlying issue, you may try to enable [diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)  for your web app. This should provide more information on what is happening at the storage level and what kind of activity is going on.